# Doing equivalent test between superclass and subclass without instantiating the subclass

Tags: java

Just playing with java fundamentals I came up with question whether I can check inheritance between two .class objects without instantiating them.

For example, if I have a class Foo, which is a subclass of Baa:
`Foo a = new Foo(); return a instanceof Baa` will return true.

But what do I have to do if I wanna do the equivalent test with Foo.class and Baa.class?
I think I can do something like this:
`Foo.class.newInstance() instanceof Baa.class`
But would it be possible to test the same without instantiating Foo?

Comment: If you don't mind loading the class you can use [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)). If you don't want to load the class you'll have to inspect the byte code (which you should use a library to do).

Comment: Thank you. IsAssignableFrom(Class) will do for me.  Inspecting byte code requires too much knowledge for my level:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) to check the hierarchy in inheritance. According to java-docs:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

This will not instantiate any of the classes and you will get the desired functionality.